# New Podfile format in flutter - How to achieve the same as before?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, podfile

Since the newest flutter version there is a new structure of the `Podfile`. For the `ffmpeg` package I have to add some additional packages to the podfile. But with the new version I don´t know how to handle this.

**This is the old structure of the required part**

```
  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
        pod name+'/full-gpl-lts', :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios') // I need this!
    else
        pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
    end
  end
```

**How I tried to put this in the new structure**

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', 'flutter_ffmpeg')
  File.symlink(path, symlink)
  pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/https-gpl', :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
end
```

But I can´t get it to work. I get the error `[!] Invalid` Podfile `file: File exists @ syserr_fail2_in - .symlinks/plugins/flutter_ffmpeg.`

Do you have an idea how to write this in the new `Podfile` format?

Answer (score 1):

[This commit](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/59044/files/40b21e52153e1246120e90d1c757c0ec4c34ebb0) seems to be the one that changed podfile structure in flutter tools.
It introduces

```
def flutter_install_all_ios_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  flutter_install_ios_engine_pod(ios_application_path)
  flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path)
end
```

**What happens is your code**

The symlink for flutter_ffmpeg is already created by *flutter_install_all_ios_pods* and so is the pod.

**What I would do**

I don't know of a way to remove a pod and i don't want to fork flutter's podhelper, so I would duplicate their method like so:

```
# Create this "fork" of flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods
def install_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
 # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)

    # Changes relative to flutter_ffmpeg
    if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
        pod name+'/https-gpl', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
    else
        pod name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Remove this line
  # flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  flutter_install_ios_engine_pod(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  install_plugin_pods(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

I cannot test this until tomorrow, i will update this post then.

Comment: I tried this solution didn't work