# How do I specify the flutter-ffmpeg package in iOS Podfile?

Tags: ios, flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-dependencies, podfile

Based on: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63355721/new-podfile-format-in-flutter-how-to-achieve-the-same-as-before),
I believe that they changed Podfiles such that this code (from a tutorial):

```
if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
  pod name+'/min-gpl-lts', :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
else
  pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
```

and this code in the ffmpeg-flutter docs:
"Modify the default `#Plugin Pods` block as follows:"

```
# Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
        pod name+'/<package name>', :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
    else
        pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
    end
  end
```

No longer work. This is what my current Podfile looks like. What do I add so that I can specify my flutter_ffmpeg  as "/min-gpl-lts."

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.3'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
#pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/min-gpl-lts' # when i uncomment this line, it says "multiple sources for dependency"

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I have tried this Podfile with the suggestion of "forking" the function out:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.3'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

# Create this "fork" of flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods
def install_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
   ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
   raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path
 
   # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
   # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
 
   symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
   system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.
 
   symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
   system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)
 
   plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins')
   plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
   plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
     symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, name)
     File.symlink(path, symlink)
 
     # Changes relative to flutter_ffmpeg
     if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
         pod name+'/min-gpl-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
     else
         pod name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
     end
   end
 end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  # this function ^ is specified as follows
  # def flutter_install_all_ios_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  #   flutter_install_ios_engine_pod(ios_application_path)
  #   flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path)
  # end

  # use this subcall to do the first half of the above^ function
  flutter_install_ios_engine_pod File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  # use our "fork" to install the plug in pods (exactly the same as
  # the original function but with ffmpeg package specified)
  install_plugin_pods(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

But this gives me an error in Xcode's `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m`: `Module 'apple_sign_in'not found.` So I think the Podfile is not working.

I also tried this, where I pass `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))` to the function `install_plugin_pods`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.3'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

# Create this "fork" of flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods
def install_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
   ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
   raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path
 
   # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
   # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
 
   symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
   system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.
 
   symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
   system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)
 
   plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins')
   plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
   plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
     symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, name)
     File.symlink(path, symlink)
 
     # Changes relative to flutter_ffmpeg
     if name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
         pod name+'/min-gpl-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
     else
         pod name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name, 'ios')
     end
   end
 end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  # this function ^ is specified as follows
  # def flutter_install_all_ios_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  #   flutter_install_ios_engine_pod(ios_application_path)
  #   flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path)
  # end

  # use this subcall to do the first half of the above^ function
  flutter_install_ios_engine_pod File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  # use our "fork" to install the plug in pods (exactly the same as
  # the original function but with ffmpeg package specified)
  install_plugin_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

However, this gives me a `Error running pod install.` I run `flutter clean` between builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following method to your new `Podfile` and replace the `<package name>` with `flutter_ffmpeg` package name.

```
def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  # defined_in_file is set by CocoaPods and is a Pathname to the Podfile.
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
          pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/<package name>', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      else
          pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

2. Make sure that `Runner` target calls `flutter_install_all_ios_pods`.

```
target 'Runner' do
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end
```

Comment: Huge. Also, to get it to build a release version (`flutter build ios`) make sure you go into Runner.xcworkspace in Xcode and set the target version to 9.3 or higher (the pubspec target version didn't affect my Xcode version for whatever reason).